# Configure Port Forwarding / Virtual Server Routing in Fiber to Home modems

Tags: port, virtual, forwarding

Recently BSNL has launched Fiber To The Home (FTTH) Optic Fiber Based Broadband service. Since professional class optic fiber Modem unit is costly, they provide basic modem through which end user can access broadband / voip / IPTv only.

Before that I was using traditional Copper wire ADSL Modems, that was equipped with all professional class features like Port Forwarding, Virtual Server, URL forwarding, Wi-Fi etc.

Can any one guide me how to configure Port Forwarding / Virtual Server configuration in FTTH setup?

The FTTH devices used are:

1. Terracom fiberhome AN5006-04
2. Huawaei EchoLife HG850a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research following setup worked:

1. Connect Optic Fiber cable to FTTH Modem, reset FTTH Modem to factory setting OR delete all configuration parameters so that it's configuration matches with factory setting, now configure it in bridge mode only. Please don't put user id & passwords etc.
2. Connect any common Router (Wi-Fi can also be used depending on need), with FTTH Modem. Please ensure that IP Address series should be same for both devices. Generally FTTH Modems comes with IP Address 192.168.100.1 and Routers have 192.168.1.1. Please don't use ADSL Modems / Routers.
3. Configure router in bridge mode with dialer values i.e. login id, password, static ip, gateway etc. in Router
4. Configure port forwarding / virtual server as per the need.

Everything configured, now enjoy fiber optic high speed flawless internet service.

Cheers!!!

Comment: I got FFTH internet connection with Huawei EchoLife HG850a router. It has 4 lan ports but no built in setting for Wifi. How can I connect a Wifi Router?

Comment: @user2207 I am unable to setup the FTTH modem HG850a in bridge mode. Can you share a screenshot of your modem configuration to show how you have setup the bridge mode. I could not find the option to setup in bridge mode.

Comment: Did it ! Thanks for the hint to setup PPPoE on router instead of modem.

Answer (score 0):

I also had same problem with me so I contacted Huawei support team. Huawei support team confirmed me that HG850a Doesn't support port forwarding.

Comment: After a lot of research following setup worked: